Select table view for workbook and retrieve results in SuiteScript 2
Although I have some experience with SuiteScript, I haven't really done anything with workbooks either in NetSuite itself, or SuiteScript. I have a task to do that though. All I'm trying to do is retrieve the results of an existing workbook. I found you can do that fairly easily like:
var loadedQuery = query.load({id:'custworbook_some_existing_workbook_id'});
            
var resultSet = loadedQuery.run();
            
// resultSet.results contains your records

That works fine for certain workbooks, but if there are multiple table views attached to the workbook, it throws a WORKBOOK_MORE_TABLEVIEWS_ARE_ASSIGNED exception.
I assumed that I probably just needed to somehow identify the existing table view I wanted to use for that workbook, but I'm not seeing how to accomplish that in SuiteScript, although I have a feeling it's probably right in front of me. Or could it be you just can't do this with workbooks that have multiple table views associated with them?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

So of course, as soon as I posted the question I finally figured it out. You just need the ID of the table view you want to see, and use that in the query.load call.
Also, you can get a list of tables for a particular workbook like this:
var tables = query.listTables({workbookId: workbookId});

That will return a list of tables that show the IDs that look like custview108_123456789
Then just use that ID:
query.load({id: 'custview108_123456789'});
Hope this helps someone
